# Sci-Fi fantasy book about boy with powers?

Tags: story-identification, books, telekinesis

A boy is in a community where only certain people have some sort of telekinetic powers and his brother has them. The society leaders believe the brother is the 'chosen one' but it's actually the main character. A specific scene had him fighting his brother and was pushed into some water and he was drowning, but he 'discovered' his power by teaching his body to change the water molecules to oxygen. I have no clue what the book is called but it is driving me crazy that I don't know it.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend a look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to story id questions, which may remind you of some additional details. This, in turn, may help someone to answer your question.

Comment: This is making me think of a book I asked about in here recently. It was answered and  titled Worldstorm by James Lovegrove and had Air and Fire and Water powers amongst select members of the community. I still need to get a copy for my re-read so am not 100% about the scene described above

Comment: @Danny3414 that was probably me who IDed Worldstorm. I don't remember anything in it about a chosen one or converting water to oxygen,

Answer (score 2):

*[Freakling](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13438522-freakling)* by Lana Krumwiede

> In twelve-year-old Taemon’s city, everyone has a power called psi—the ability to move and manipulate objects with their minds. When Taemon loses his psi in a traumatic accident, he must hide his lack of power by any means possible. But a humiliating incident at a sports tournament exposes his disability, and Taemon is exiled to the powerless colony.
>
> The "dud farm" is not what Taemon expected, though: people are kind and open, and they actually seem to enjoy using their hands to work and play and even comfort their children. Taemon adjusts to his new life quickly, making friends and finding unconditional acceptance.
>
> But gradually he discovers that for all its openness, there are mysteries at the colony, too—dangerous secrets that would give unchecked power to psi wielders if discovered.
>
> When Taemon unwittingly leaks one of these secrets, will he have the courage to repair the damage—even if it means returning to the city and facing the very people who exiled him?

Comment: Could you perhaps describe why you think it matches, such as the wrestling scene in the original post? The plot summary from your answer doesn’t entirely match that found in the question.