# Young adult book about a boy who lives in a community of people with telekinetic powers

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, telekinesis

It’s a book about a boy who lives in a community of people with telekinetic powers, however he has clairvoyance(?).
He ends up being sent to a farm where he learns the truth of his world and leaves his community. It’s a newish book, published in the 2000s to mid-2010s

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

*[Freakling](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13438522-freakling)* by Lana Krumwiede

[image: Front cover of Freakling]

> In twelve-year-old Taemon’s city, everyone has a power called psi—the ability to move and manipulate objects with their minds. When Taemon loses his psi in a traumatic accident, he must hide his lack of power by any means possible. But a humiliating incident at a sports tournament exposes his disability, and Taemon is exiled to the powerless colony.
>
> The "dud farm" is not what Taemon expected, though: people are kind and open, and they actually seem to enjoy using their hands to work and play and even comfort their children. Taemon adjusts to his new life quickly, making friends and finding unconditional acceptance.
>
> But gradually he discovers that for all its openness, there are mysteries at the colony, too—dangerous secrets that would give unchecked power to psi wielders if discovered.
>
> When Taemon unwittingly leaks one of these secrets, will he have the courage to repair the damage—even if it means returning to the city and facing the very people who exiled him?

Found with a search for `site:goodreads.com community of telekinetics`, which led to [this "What's the Name of this Book?" question](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/22097893-solved-ya-fantasy-2000s-book-about-a-boy-who-lives-in-a-world-where-eve).

Comment: Unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188378/sci-fi-fantasy-book-about-boy-with-powers?rq=1